# Redirect http to https automatically - web.config - Plesk 12.0.18 for Windows

Tags: windows, web-config, plesk

I need to redirect users automatically to the secure https connection. As I found out after a lot of reading on a Windows server this happens through web.config file. I tried many options but nothing worked and I am not even sure anymore was there a web.config file in folder httpdocs or I create it. With this being said is there a way to find out which web.config file is in use as I created a billion of them in different directories (ok just 2) and what do I need in it to make it redirect the visitors automatically?

Update asked from Oleg:

- SSL is enabled on the domain which is goliax.com
- Requested URL in browser is [goliax.com](http://goliax.com) and if the redirection was working it would have opened [secured connection goliax.com](https://goliax.com) instead
- Everything I do in the root directory can be seen in a browser right after applying the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `httpdocs/web.config` works for me on Windows 2012:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors>
        <error statusCode="400" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\bad_request.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="401" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\unauthorized.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="403" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\forbidden.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_found.html"/><remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="405" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\method_not_allowed.html"/><remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="406" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_acceptable.html"/>
        <error statusCode="407" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\proxy_authentication_required.html"/><remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1"/>
        <error statusCode="412" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\precondition_failed.html"/>
        <error statusCode="414" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\request-uri_too_long.html"/><error statusCode="415" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\unsupported_media_type.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/><error statusCode="500" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\internal_server_error.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1"/><error statusCode="501" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_implemented.html"/>
        <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1"/><error statusCode="502" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\bad_gateway.html"/>
        <error statusCode="503" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\maintenance.html"/>
    </httpErrors>

        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="httpsredirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This web.config should works if `URL Rewrite` module is installed in IIS.
You can find out in Plesk UI in `Tools&Settings` > `Server Components`:

[image: IIS URL rewrite module plesk]

Comment: Mine is Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 . I do not know if it would make a difference. Still no success. I tried placing the code in the web.config file in folder httpdocs and in the main folder where all my website's files are.

Comment: I've checked that this web.config is works in 2008 R2. Could you please update your question with following details: does SSL is enabled on domain? Which URL you have requesting in browser?  What exactly you've see in browser? Any other changes in web root can be observer via browser(i.e. you've add/change file and can see changes in browser)?

Comment: Update added to the question

Comment: Could you please check that URL Rewrite module is installed in IIS? You can find out it in Plesk UI in Tools&Settings > Server Components.

Comment: Yes this is the module installed - IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 7.2.1952

Comment: Do not worry we will figure it out. Btw I did follow all of the instructions word by word from what they send me from godaddy and it did not work. There is something wrong on my server it is just hard to find what exactly it is. I really appreciate your help on accessing the full php.ini file :) It was a big relief for me.

Comment: @JackGoodman You also may try to contact Plesk support directly as I know it's free now.

Comment: I did and they send me back to Godaddy. Godaddy on their behalf is sending me to Plesk. A funny story :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what file format is your web.config file?  Mine is .config but in an article I am reading now there is a pic of someone's file and his one is VisualStudio..something (from what I can see in the ftp where the pic is taken. I have also tried simple txt and nothing.

Comment: @JackGoodman "web.config" it's a general XML file, it's name is "web" and "config" extension.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: It turned out that after I upgrade Plesk to 17.XXX there was another web.config file displayed in httpdocs folder which is xml format rather than the txt which I have created earlier with the earlier Plesk version where this file did not exist [link](http://goliax.com/web.config1.png). This is what it is inside the file I discovered [link](http://goliax.com/web.config2.png) . I tried everything from this Godaddy instructions page [link](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828?v=1) in the file but nothing work. Can I see what is inside your web.config please?

Comment: @JackGoodman yep, check the answer. You can just copypaste `<rewrite>...</rewrite>` before `</system.webServer></configuration>` to your web.config.

Comment: I just try it again but I did it earlier and it still did not work. hahaha finally... I just remembered that I read somewhere that the file needs to be in the main directory and I moved it there and it worked :) I am still giving you a credit for helping me out though. Thanks a lot :)